# AO bake not working! just black image

Tags: texture-baking, baking, ambient-occlusion

I'm trying to bake the AO for my model, but when I bake it, the result is just a black image.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance

Here's the .blend file: https://mega.nz/file/sNogBSKB#PK9oYOC3l_ltyo590BlKd1wXMzD8fjTf6bakGR7GzYM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The baking process works for me when I `select` the desired bake `image node`. In this case, the image: `Untitled.002`.

[image]

Comment: strange, even when I select the image node, the bake result still is just a pure black texture.  https://i.imgur.com/rORLkkb.png

Comment: I notice you're using "GPU Rendering" for the rendering, I'd advice trying CPU to see if it's possibly that your version of Blender do not have the correct CUDA/Kernel files.